# ConstraintLayout & BottomNavigationView, fragment and controls appear underneath. GoogleMaps v3 padding?

Tags: android, google-maps, android-constraintlayout, material-components-android

ConstraintLayout & BottomNavigationView, fragment and controls appear underneath. GoogleMaps v3 padding?

My terminology may not be square here, which is likely why I can not find out what I am missing.
Given my view XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/container"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <com.google.android.material.bottomnavigation.BottomNavigationView
        android:id="@+id/nav_view"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="0dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="0dp"
        android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:menu="@menu/bottom_nav_menu" />

    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/nav_host_fragment"
        android:name="androidx.navigation.fragment.NavHostFragment"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:defaultNavHost="true"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@id/nav_view"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:navGraph="@navigation/mobile_navigation" />
</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

My `nav_host_fragment` may, depending on the user's action, have a fragment that is another `ConstraintLayout` that has one or two action buttons that are constrained to the bottom, and I get this:

[image: Screen1]

Doing what research I can, I saw two fixes. Either adding `app:layout_constrainedHeight="true"` to the `id/nav_host_fragment`, **or** changing the same fragment's `layout_width` and `layout_height` to "0dp". That works, but not with the rounded corners, as there's 'empty space':

[image: Screen2]

Note the black corners. And Google's little copyright. Is there a way to tell the GoogleMaps fragment (or its parent ConstraintLayout) to 'pad' the bottom of itself, so that the black rounded corners aren't black, and the required Goog logo and ym action buttons aren't hidden underneath?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should adjust the [padding](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android-sdk/map#map_padding) of the map to move the logo up and I think that solves your problem

> Map padding allows you to reposition these elements if necessary. If
> you display a custom UI at the bottom of the map, add padding to the
> bottom of the map so that the logo and legal notices will always be
> visible

Comment: Ah, that should work, thanks! Is there any way (preferable in XML) to get the height of the madding needed?

Comment: Not that I am aware of (for xml at least)